# Yahoo Finance API historical quote

Tags: javascript, php, api, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am using PHP and JavaScript to pull data from the yahoo finance API. For some reason the below yahoo finance API url is not pulling any financial data for yesterdays date and resulting in a 404 error. I have checked the API docs to verify the url is correct and it is. It is working for other dates, although not for the date that I need. I am simply trying to get the financial data for 2/16/15. Anyone have any idea why it is failing?

```
http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ZNGA&a=1&b=16&c=2015&d=1&e=16&f=2015
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given I'm getting a 500 error for the front page of their developer docs for this API, I'd be inclined to point the finger at their systems being down/broken in some way. Edit: it's working now, but if other dates are working I'd still point the finger at them not your code.

Comment: @Bulk, thanks for the reply, so the above URL is working for you? I am still getting a 404 on my end for the above URL. It is just very disappointing, as all other dates work except for the one I need...

Comment: Sorry no I meant their docs, that URL is a 404 for me too. My guess is their data collection systems broke yesterday and they just don't have data for that date yet - Google often has very similar problems with Analytics. You should probably build your system to deal with that eventuality and re-try later..

Answer (score 1):

No data! It's President's Day in the US on the 3rd Mon of Feb!

Comment: Interesting. I'd have thought the API wouldn't throw a 404 in such a situation, but it seems to.